# How fast do I need to draw with CVDisplayLink?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drawing, core-video

How fast do I need to draw with CVDisplayLink?

Am I correct in thinking that, after drawing my scene in my display link callback, if `CVGetCurrentHostTime() > outputTime->hostTime`, then I've dropped a frame?